# LabWindows CVI .Net Controller C#Wrapper for Cognex DataMan

Tags: c#, c, wrapper, labwindows, cvi

I need to Integrate Cognex Dataman Wireless Handheld scanner in to existing Application developed using LabWindows CVI. Cognex has provided SDK in C#.  Below SDK link

http://www.cognex.com/support/downloads/File.aspx?d=2628

I used CVI Tool .Net Controller to create C# Wrapper.
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051T-01/cvi/libref/cvidotnet_sample_code/

Below is code that suppose to connect to cognex scanner.

```
        Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector__Create (&DM_Connector, IPAddress,0);
        Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector_Set_UserName (DM_Connector,"Admin", 0);
        Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector_Set_Password (DM_Connector, "", 0);

        Cognex_DataMan_SDK_DataManSystem__Create (&DM_system, DM_Connector, 0);
        Cognex_DataMan_SDK_DataManSystem_Connect (DM_system, 0);
```

My problem is below line

```
Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector__Create (&DM_Connector, IPAddress, 0);
```

I can create execute but it's not connecting, Constructor is not taking ipaddress.

Below help on generate from C# Wrapper Prototype

```
/*
Creates a new instance of the ethernet connector with the specified system IP address.
-------------------- Prototype 
int Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector__Create
(Cognex_DataMan_SDK_EthSystemConnector *Instance_Handle,
                System_Net_IPAddress address,
                CDotNetHandle *Exception_Handle);
```

Please advise , I have no success so far with this
Thank You